# Zenyatta's Orb of Discord and Reinhardt's shield

Tags: overwatch

Does placing an Orb of Discord on Reinhardt increase the amount of damage his shield takes?

*Bonus question:* I have noticed that when playing Zenyatta, I can not throw an Orb of Discord through a Reinhardt shield. Are there any mechanics that help with getting on Orb onto a shielded Reinhardt / a character hiding behind a Reinhardt shield?

Comment: Mostly I just mash my L1 button until it breaks through the shield. A lot of Reinhardts, at least on PS4, are really only out for themselves. As soon as an enemy gets past their shield, they turn to face them, exposing their back. Otherwise, there's no way to get through a shield.

Answer (score 4):

Zenyatta's Orb of Discord has no effect on Reinhardt's or Winston's barriers, and it is impossible to use it on an enemy covered by one.

Comment: That's pretty surprising that Reinhardt's barrier doesn't take any extra damage. Have a source for that?

Comment: I should be able to test this later

Comment: @DCShannon My source is from playing as both Reinahrdt and Zenyatta multiple times in that scenario.

Comment: It would be nice to get a definitive test in private matches.